# min(date) in sqldf in R is not converting into date format

Tags: r, sqldf

Data:

```
test <- read.table(text = "
user_id    event_captured_dt     send_dt
656072342         2016-12-30  2016-10-24
656072342         2016-11-10  2016-10-24
656072342         2016-11-15  2016-10-24
656072342         2016-11-21  2016-10-24
656072342         2016-11-23  2016-10-24
656072342         2017-03-07  2016-10-24
", header = TRUE)
test$event_captured_dt <- as.Date(test$event_captured_dt,format = '%Y-%m-%d')
test$send_dt <- as.Date(test$send_dt,format = '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Am querying min(send_date) in sqldf but its giving int format op but i need it in date format.

```
sqldf('select date(min(event_captured_dt), "unixepoch","localtime") min_dt, send_dt from test group by send_dt')
```

expected o/p is:min_dt    send_dt
              1 2016-11-10 2016-10-24
current o/p is: min_dt    send_dt
              1 1970-01-01 2016-10-24

Comment: I can reproduce this and edited the question to make the error reproducible.

Comment: Added mockupcode, please help!!

Comment: Can you please roll back your new edit? It ***was*** reproducible like I've left it.

Comment: Solution : `events_sends_df$event_captured_dt <- as.character(events_sends_df$event_captured_dt)` then run the select statement.

Answer (score 1):

Convert your dates like this:

```
test$event_captured_dt <- as.POSIXct(test$event_captured_dt,format = '%Y-%m-%d')
test$send_dt <- as.POSIXct(test$send_dt,format = '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Now go ahead with your query as usual:

```
sqldf('select date(min(event_captured_dt), "unixepoch", "localtime") min_dt, send_dt from test group by send_dt')
```

Output:

```
      min_dt    send_dt
1 2016-11-10 2016-10-24
```

Answer (score 1):

This has been answered numerous times on SO and is also an sqldf FAQ.  See *FAQ #4. How does sqldf work with "Date" class variables?* at https://github.com/ggrothendieck/sqldf .

To reiterate, the default backend, SQLite, does not have a date type.

### H2

If you want to use Date class variables the easiest thing to do is to use the RH2 backend since H2 does have a date type.  If RH2 is loaded sqldf will notice it and use it.

```
library(RH2)
library(sqldf)

sqldf('select 
    min(event_captured_dt) min_dt,
    send_dt 
  from test
  group by send_dt')
##       min_dt    send_dt
## 1 2016-11-10 2016-10-24
```

### SQLite

If you want to use the default RSQLite backend then be sure that RH2 is NOT loaded (or otherwise specify SQLite to sqldf as per `?sqldf`).  You can use the `verbose=TRUE` argument to `sqldf` to get more info including which backend is being used.

Since SQLite does not support dates `Date` class variables are sent to SQLite as numeric (number of days since UNIX Epoch) and are returned to R similarly.  If the `sqldf` argument `method="auto"` is in effect (which it normally is because that is the default) then it will interpret returned numeric columns as `Date` if the name of that column was of `Date` class in the input.  If you change the method to `method="Date"` then all numeric columns returned will be regarded as `Date`.  If you use `method="name__class"` then if the name of a returned column ends with two underscores and an R class name then `sqldf` will convert the column to that class and remove the underscores and class from the name.  Thus these will work.  Make sure that RH2 is NOT loaded.  (If it is loaded, unload it or restart R.)  See the documentation of the `method` argument in `?sqldf` for more info.

```
library(sqldf)

# using method="Date"
sqldf('select 
    min(event_captured_dt) min_dt,
    send_dt 
  from test
  group by send_dt', method = "Date")
##       min_dt    send_dt
## 1 2016-11-10 2016-10-24
```

or

```
library(sqldf)

# using method="name__class"
sqldf('select 
    min(event_captured_dt) min_dt__Date,
    send_dt send_dt__Date
  from test
  group by send_dt', method = "name__class")
##       min_dt    send_dt
## 1 2016-11-10 2016-10-24
```

Comment: Thank you so much Grothendieck. As am new to R it's really needed and useful post.